# No printers showing when component service tries to print

Tags: vb6

I have this old component service (COM+ Application) that gets called and tries to print a document.  It runs as a specific user that acts as a service account that is never actually logged on to.  For some reason my debug output is showing 0 printers listed when I make the call to the COM+ App.  However, if I open a command prompt as that user I can make the same call and see all the printers.

It's like it's requiring the profile to be loaded before printers are shown.  Is there a way around this?  Currently my only work around is to do something really crazy like schedule a task to run each day for 1 day that just runs `cmd.exe /c "pause"`.  I didn't have to do this in the past (this has been used for many years).  I remember something about not unloading registry profiles that might have helped me.  Is there anything that I can add to my application (com+ app) that could load the printers and make them available for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like I was on the right track just needed to know exactly what to search for.  It seems `Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff` was what I was after.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/application-management/complus-server-application-not-work

Adding this to your registry will stop the profiles from getting logged off after they have logged on once.

Save a file with the contents below and name it something like `Disable Profile Logoff.reg` then double click it to add it to your registry.

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System]
"DisableForceUnload"=dword:00000001
```